# 3 netsed For loops

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I'm trying to create three for loop as below but cant figure it out yet.
first of all I have two arrays one with 16 variables and one with 17 variables.
What I'm trying to achieve is create a new matrix (DIST) with only two columns and 16*17=272 rows.

So technically for row 1 and column 1 of DIST the algorithm should read first element of "X_range" and for row 1 and column 2 it should read first element of "Y_range"
moving to second row AGAIN first element of "X_range" BUT second element of "Y_range" until "k = 1:length(Y_range)" reach the end and we move to second element of "X_range".

In meantime the "i" which is the row of DIST should move from 1 to n=272 so that the values can be placed correctly.

However the following code wont work and I know my nested FOR loops are definately incorrect!

```
X_range = 1:16;
Y_range = 1:17;

n = length(X_range)*length(Y_range);
DIST= zeros(n, 2);

for i = 1:n
    for j = 1:length(X_range)
        for k = 1:length(Y_range)
            Dist(i, 1) = X_range(j)
            Dist(i, 2) = Y_range(k)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: This has a simple solution in MATLAB: write the results into a 3D matrix `Dist(j,k,:)`, and then reshape the array to be 2D: `Dict = reshape(Dist,[],2)`. Note that you can replace your loops with a call to `meshgrid`.

Comment: Can you please edit the code with your answer?! I'm new to matlab !

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, the following code should work

`X_range = 1:16; 
Y_range = 1:17;  

n = length(X_range)*length(Y_range); 
DIST= zeros(n, 2); 

DIST(:,1) = repmat(X_range',[length(Y_range),1]); 
DIST(:,2) = repmat(Y_range',[length(X_range),1]);`